# R pglm probit estimation: uninformative error "object 'Li' not found"

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, statistics

Using the setup:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
t <- c(1,2,1,2,1,1)
x <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1)
y <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(id, t, x, y)
```

Preparing fitted values from an OLS regression as the starting values:

```
tstart <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
```

Running probit:

```
tfit <- pglm(y ~ x, data = df, index = c("id","t"), 
    model = "within", family = binomial('probit'), start = tstart$fitted.values)
```

Returns the error

```
Error in lnl.binomial(param = start, y = y, X = X, id = id, model = model,  : 
object 'Li' not found
```

This error seems very uninformative to me.
I am not even looking for some object 'Li' in any of the calls, and have no idea what this object should be. 
The traceback makes it seem to occur in the function:

```
9: lnl.binomial(param = start, y = y, X = X, id = id, model = model, 
   link = link, rn = rn) at <text>#1
```

But trying to look at the code of the function for when the error occurs reveals that there is not even a function

```
lnl.binomial()
```

Where did I go wrong about this?

Comment: `lnl.binomial` in function, which is passed to `eval`, so that is the reason you can not find it

Comment: @Zbynek could you explain that further? I am new to R and I do not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: if you look at the code of `pglm`, in the bottom, you will see lines: `thefunc <- paste("function(start) attr(lnl.", family, "(", 
                   argschar(args), "), \"gradient\")", sep = "")`
which means, that a string is formed, including `lnl.binomial` and this string is evaluated outside of R (it is most likely a C program). But that is as much, as I know.

Comment: @Zbynek thank you!
So that basically means that the error comes from somewhere outside of R.
That still leaves the problem that the error message is insufficient to figure out what is wrong ...

Comment: perhaps you could write to the developers of `pglm` package, or try the analysis with different data to see, if the problem persists

Comment: @Zbynek, Well I wrote to the Author but haven't got a reply so far. Can you suggest any other way to approach a panel-data probit model in R?

Comment: I am sorry, but this is beyond my knowledge

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: @JonM Not really an answer to what exactly doesn't work, no. I vaguely remember that it had to do something with the "within" and "between" estimators. I think I circumvented the problem by using another package or estimation method.